Wireshark quick unexpectedly whenever I click open file or save file
I am using UTM virtual machine for Ubuntu server and desktop in my Apple silicon M1 chip Macbook. I installed Wireshark via Ubuntu terminal. It worked and it can smoothly run the packets. The problem is when I try to save the file or I want to open file in Wireshark, the app quit suddenly. So, I am having problem in clicking open file or save in menu bar in Wireshark.
Ubuntu version - 24.10,
Wireshark version - 4.2.6 (Git v4.2.6 packaged as 4.2.6-1).

don't you mean quit?
